# ROR: undefined method ` ' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined

Environment: Rails 3.0.1, MySQL
I have a Users table, and I want to search for users by city.

I have the following code in users_controller:

```
def output
@results = User.select(:fname, :lname).where(['city = ?', params[:text1]]).all
```

output.html.erb in View:

```
<% @results.each do |r| %>
<%= @r.fname %>
<%= @r.lname %>
<% end %>
```

It will show up as **undefined method `fname' for nil:NilClass**.
However, if I type following in View, it works:

```
your search are <%= @results %>
```

The output is:

```
your search are [#<User fname: "adam", lname: "huang">, #<User fname: "eric", lname: "huang">]
```

The Users table is:

```
  class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.integer :uid
      t.string :email
      t.string :password
      t.string :fname
      t.string :lname
      t.string :city
      t.integer :pid

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<% @results.each do |r| %>
<%= r.fname %>
<%= r.lname %>
<% end %>
```

It looks like you did a simple typo.